# Como saber se passei da meia noite ou um novo dia começou?

Tags: android

Preciso fazer um fazer um `if` para quando passar da meia noite, mas como posso obter esta informação mesmo com o celular desligado?

Estou tentando assim atualmente:

```
date_current = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
if (date_current.getTime() == 0){
    dados.setmeianoite(true);
}
```

Porém se passa da meia noite enquanto o celular está em background ou desligado ele não cai no `if`, consequentemente não faz o que quero.

O que preciso saber é se ele virou a meia noite e não se é meia noite.

Comment: Esta rodando isso num Service para rodar algo em segundo plano? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Sim, estou rodando num service

Comment: Olha, para rodar um programa com o celular desligado, só fazendo pacto com o demônio.

Comment: Esta pergunta tem cheiro de [**problema XY**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132) - Acho que você não tem que dar um `setmeianoite(true);`, e sim ver qual é a última data em que algo aconteceu e comparar com a data atual, se estão em dias diferentes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_current.getTime() == 0` só vai retornar `true` quando for [meia noite do dia 1 de janeiro de 1970 (epoch)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()).

A forma mais simples de verificar as horas é utilizando um [Calendar.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
date_current = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date_current);

if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 0) {
  dados.setmeianoite(true);
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz mais ou menos isso, porem tambem acrescentei uma verificação no boot do device, pq desta maneira, se essa hora vira quando o celular estar desligado, ele não seta true.

Answer (score 2):

Não conheço muito bem Java nem Android, mas acredito ser uma questão de algoritmo aqui.

Para começar, veja [a resposta do Leonardo Lima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/249801/1658). Seu programa compara a data-hora atual com uma data específica, não com a meia noite do dia em que você está.

Mas ainda falta mais uma coisa. Seu programa roda de tempos em tempos, certo? O que eu sugiro:

- A cada vez que o trecho relevante for executado, guarde nos dados da sua aplicação a data-hora na qual o trecho foi executado.
- Ainda nesse trecho, compare a data atual com a data da última vez em que o programa foi executado.

Você não precisa levar a hora em consideração. Se a data atual e a data da última execução forem diferentes, então o dia "virou" desde a última vez que o programa executou.